# Groupby / Cube and sum values from distinct rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe like this:

```
name |   A   | Number
--------------------
Dan  |  1    | 1.5
Jan  |  1    | 2.5
Dan  |  1    | 1.5
Ann  |  1    | 1.5
Ann  |  2    | 1.2
Jon  |  2    | 1.7
```

There are a name column and an associated value with them in the Number column. A name will have a corresponding Number always, ie if Dan have value 1.5, wherever Dan appears in data the Number associated will be 1.5.

I want to groupby on column A and find the distinct sum of Number for unique names.

For example, For group 1,  unique names are Dan, Jan and Ann. Their corresponding Numbers are 1.5, 2.5, 1.5 which sums to 5.5.

I tried to solve this by making a dummy column, collecting it to a set by group and later explode it and sum. The code looks like this,

```
sdf = sdf.withColumn("dummy_col", F.concat(F.col("name"), F.lit("_"), F.col("Number")))

sdf = sdf.groupby("A") \
        .agg(F.collect_set("dummy_col").alias("dummy_set"))
  
sdf = sdf.withColumn("exploded", F.explode("dummy_set")) \
  .withColumn("Number_new", F.split("exploded")[1])

sdf_final = sdf.groupby("A") \
  .agg(F.sum("Number_new").alias("Sum"))
```

But this solution is not scalable at all. It takes very long to run when the data is millions of rows.

I'm running spark 2.3 and I can't upgrade it as well.

I'm looking for a solution that scales well with data size and something in fewer steps. Also, I'll have to do a cube over a few columns like A, B, C and D instead of groupby on A and do similar sum.

What I want is to run a cube instead of groupby. drop_duplicates won't help me there. Also, my keys are many columns not just a column A.

Alternative to cube, I can create a list of groupby levels and run a loop and process it one by one to use drop_duplicates.

Which still lead to issues related to performance. I haven't tried it though. But I can see the list of groupby keys being at least 100 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`drop_duplicates`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates) using the subset of columns 'name' and 'A' and then `groupby` and `sum`:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['name', 'A'])\
.groupby('A').agg(F.sum('Number').alias('Sum')).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+
|  A|Sum|
+---+---+
|  1|5.5|
|  2|2.9|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Zotka, Thanks for your answer. I've updated the Q. Sorry I missed out to add the details earlier.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['name', 'A']).cube('name', 'Number').sum()`?